# Why is autowired properties file null?

Tags: java, xml, spring, unit-testing, autowired

I autowired some beans from my testConfig.xml, and it works fine but when I want to autowire a properties file it gives null, the properties file is near of my xml in selenium folder. My testConfig.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd" >

    <bean id="base" class="java.net.URI">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8080/MySite" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="siteBase" class="java.net.URI">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8080/MySite/site" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="adminBase" class="java.net.URI">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8080/MySite/admin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="firefoxDriver" class="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver" destroy-method="quit"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <util:properties id="seleniumSelectors" location="classpath:selenium/selenium-selectors.properties"/>
</beans>
```

and here I want to autowire it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testConfig.xml" })
public abstract class AbstractUITest extends TestCase{


    @Autowired
    protected URI base;


    @Autowired
    protected URI siteBase;


    @Autowired
    protected URI adminBase;


    @Autowired
    protected WebDriver firefoxDriver;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("seleniumSelectors")
    protected Properties selectors;

    protected By getBySelectorKey(String key){
        if(key.endsWith(".xpath")){
            return By.xpath(selenium.getProperty(key));
        }
    }
```

Just the selectors object is null and I don`t know why, any suggest?

UPDATE 2:

I made a mistake everithing is null when the selector is null.I cheked Initialization in my test runs before autowired, somehow this

```
public class AdminCandidatesPageUITest extends AbstractAdminUITest {

    private By COMPONENT_QUERY_TEXTBOX_EMAIL = getBySelectorKey("admin.candidates.edit.textbox.email.xpath");
    private By COMPONENT_QUERY_TEXTBOX_EMAIL_ERROR = getBySelectorKey("admin.candidates.edit.textbox.email.errors.xpath");
```

should run after seleniumSelector is autowired. Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move tag `<context:annotation-config/>` one line down. I am not sure but it seems that wiring triggered by this tag happens *before* creating of `seleniumSelectors`, so it is still `null` at the moment.

BTW if you mark your properties as `@Required` the context will fail to start and throw exception because one of the properties is not wired. This is probably preferable than failing later at runtime.

Comment: I tried to move <context:annotation-config/> under  <util:properties id="seleniumSelectors" location="classpath:selenium/selenium-selectors.properties"/> but still gives null

Comment: Try to temporarily replace  `<util:properties` by regular bean definition with class `java.util.Properties`

Comment: Can you write an example? I`m not sure cause I write correctly. I make something like this and did not work : 
<bean id="seleniumSelectors" class="java.util.Properties">

   <property name="basename" value="classpath:selenium/selenium-selectors.properties" />
  </bean> and in class  @Autowired
    protected Properties seleniumSelectors;